# Call @RequestScoped Bean from @PreDestroy method

Tags: cdi, lifecycle

I have application logic to write a protocol file in a @RequestScoped bean. I would like to write the protocol just before a @SessionScoped bean expires.

```
@SessionScoped
class Anybean implements Serializable {

@Inject
private ProtocolBean protocolBean;

@PreDestroy
private void writeFinalProtocol() {
    protocolBean.writeProtocol();

}
```

}

I get the error: WELD-000019 Error destroying an instance Managed Bean. Is it generally disallowed to call other beans from @PreDestroy?

Comment: How you are injecting `protocolBean` into `anyBean`?

Comment: What is the error? Post the stack trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I found out: As soon as I change the ProtocolBean to @SessionScoped or @ApplicationScoped everything works fine. It seems as if you cannot instantiate a RequestScoped bean wihtin a @PreDestroy method and call a method on it.

The underlaying exception is: com.sun.jdi.InvocationException occurred invoking method